# After mounting a second pod to Local-Storage PVC in Kubernetes v 1.27, first pod loses permissions to directory

Tags: kubernetes, file-permissions

Using local storage to store data files to /data/dummy1.
This works fine forever as long as I can tell.  I have the pod running as root performing basic file generation & writes.

A second container mounts to the same PVC to monitor the directory.
As soon as the second container mounts, the first container loses permissions for /data as root.  Even exec-ing into the pod/container I cannot do ls /data/dummy1 anymore.

Both pods are running on the same node, Pod 2 now does have access to the directory.  I can see the files written on the host system

fsGroup, runAsUser, and runAsGroup are all the same and root between pods.

rhel 8.8
xfs filesystem

pvc.yaml

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pvc-3
  namespace: dummy 
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage 
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  volumeName: pv-3
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

deploy-spec.yaml

```
...
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data
          name: local-persistent-storage
      volumes:
        - name: local-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc-3
```

Tried:
Mount pod1 to local-storage pvc, read/write files
Mount pod2 to same local-storage pvc, read/write files.

Expected:
ability to read and write files from 2 pods with same security context on the same node mounted to the same local-storage pvc

Actual:
Pod2 gained access to read/write and Pod1 lost access

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer was in the way selinux flags were being modified on pod/container startup.

I modified the directory
`sudo chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t s0 [directory path]`